# Convert or add a localy installed linux distro to PXE-boot server

Tags: linux, boot, iso-image, network-adapter, pxe

I have a Linux distro installed (debian) and configured in a VM.

I'm looking for a way to add it to my PXE-server so that clients can boot to it (live session)

Very confused at the moment, should i just make an ISO.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: That depends - what do you want hosted where? In particular, should the client have a copy of the filesystem (that they won't be able to persist) or do you want to mount a NFS-shared filesystem? In the latter case you'd just need a kernel and a minimal boot image in the PXE image.

Comment: I wish to host the whole thing on the PXE server  (Cent-OS) 
when other clients boots  from it they have to have the option to load the distro.